# How to revert a string back to a list of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, airflow

For some context, I'm working within Airflow and exchanging data between task objects within a DAG.  Python version is 3.6.5.

I have a method that queries a database for a rowset, which is returned as list of arrays that looks like this:

```
[
('database_name','schema_name','table_name'),
('database_name','schema_name','table_name2'),
('database_name','schema_name','table_name3')
]
```

Right when this is created, I can iterate through the values easily with a for loop.  However I run into a problem where when I pass it through an XCOM variable so that the list of arrays can be passed to and used by the next task object. The entire thing is converted into a string in transit and so I can't iterate through the arrays and their values with a for loop in the next destination task object.

Is there a specific way to cast this string back to a list of arrays?  I've tried several ways that I found online but they end up just breaking everything up into individual characters or some other result that differs from the original state.  Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying at pull your XCom variable via templates, therefore String. Modify the Operator which will be using your list of arrays.

```
class OperatorThatPullsTheArray(BaseOperator):
    ...
    def execute(self, context):
        list_of_arrays = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=self.prev_task_id) #pass the prev task id
        for array in list_of_arrays:
            ...
```

Also it is not recommended to use XCom to pass large values.

Comment: Hi @ineedhelp, thanks for answering.  

Yes I do use the templates dict in the next task which is the standard PythonOperator class.  Forgive my ignorance as my main competency is databases and sql.  Are you saying I should extend the PythonOperator class by creating my own on top of it and overriding the execute method?

I was originally going to define a method and then have the PythonOperator call it but it sounds like in this scenario I would take that method and stick it into this new class and call it from the execute method?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @GlenP, there would be better approaches to your problem but my suggestion would be to use PythonOperator to call your first method which returns the list of arrays (XCom=true). The value returned from the function will be stored in xcom.

Comment: Then for the second task, write a custom operator, which is very easy, pull your list of arrays from the execute method as I have given in the answer. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#

Comment: Thank you for the references.  This morning I finally figured out that the XCOM really wasn't needed.  Instead I adjusted the method I created to return the rowset as the list of arrays, then accessed that method directly in a for loop.  Inside the for loop I used the values for each row to define a sql query using the .format() function and fed the formatted query into a SnowflakeOperator task, then set that task downstream from a DummyOperator task as a point of origin (allowing parallel SnowflakeOperator tasks to run off that start point).  Thanks for helping think this through.